# Custom location of persistence.xml in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, persistence.xml

Is there any property in Hibernate for locating custom location of `persistence.xml` other than `/META-INF/`?

I found EclipseLink defined [`eclipselink.persistencesml`].(http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/p_persistencexml.htm#persistencexml)

What is the property for Hibernate? So that I can use them with `Persistence@createEntityManagerFactory` with additional properties?

Comment: As far as I know you can use *Spring* for to do such things.

Comment: There are some ways to apply config in persistence.xml programmatically:  


  [1]: https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-bootstrap-hibernate-without-the-persistence-xml-file/
  [2]: https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-bootstrap-jpa-programmatically-without-the-persistence-xml-configuration-file/